# How to parse this json data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i'm getting the json data,i need only the image link but i'm getting  tag also.

`jsonObject.getString(SampadaRestApiContract.JSON_TAG_BOOK_IMAGE)
   Log.d("IMAGE LINK","LINK="+articleItem.getUriImagesSDcard());`

the output i'm getting is :
    `<img src="http://sampada.net/files/IMG_5789.JPG" width="1944" height="2592" alt="" />`

Comment: Use a regex or some sort of html parser, depending on how complex your problem is

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513670/android-parsing-html-tags-on-json-and-enabling-special-characters

Answer (score 2):

This is no more a JSON issue, as you have now a string with HTML content.
See this answer for the regex : [Regular Expression to extract src attribute from img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450108/regular-expression-to-extract-src-attribute-from-img-tag)